# RethinkDB - how to get a single document by query?

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

How can I get one document only by query in RethinkDB?

for an example, I want to get the document by this query below:

```
 let searchQuery = {
    name: 'rob'
 }

var cursor = await r.table('users').filter(searchQuery).run(connection)
  var user = await cursor.toArray()
  console.log(user)
```

Result:

```
[ { email: 'fooz@bar.com',
    id: '00e18124-714b-4298-aa34-5126ebda8828',
    name: 'rob' } ]
```

[Filter method](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/) actually returns a `list of users` with the same name - 'rob'.

I want the result like [`get` method](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/get/):

```
r.table('posts').get('a9849eef-7176-4411-935b-79a6e3c56a74').run(conn, callback);
```

Result:

```
{ email: 'fooz@bar.com',
  id: '00e18124-714b-4298-aa34-5126ebda8828',
  name: 'rob' }
```

But this method **only** takes **document id**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` (by id) fetches a single row selection by design, but `filter` is a streaming operation that processes multiple values (like arrays and streams). You might want to use [`nth`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/nth/) that's designed to query for a stream/array element by its position, or its close alternative [()](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/bracket/). Here is an example:

```
.filter({ name: 'rob' })`
```

will return an array like

```
[{"email":"fooz@bar.com","id":"230de013-5d6a-436e-a7e9-a891c01913e5","name":"rob"}]
```

But the following queries

```
.filter({ name: 'rob' }).nth(0)
.filter({ name: 'rob' })(0)
```

will both return

```
{"email":"fooz@bar.com","id":"230de013-5d6a-436e-a7e9-a891c01913e5","name":"rob"}
```

Note that both also throw `ReqlNonExistenceError: Index out of bounds: 0` in case if there are no rows found. However, you can easily fix it using the `default` operator:

```
.filter({ name: 'not-rob' }).nth(0).default(null)
```

Tested using RethinkDB data explorer with the "Raw view" tab active since both "Tree view" and "Table view" display single-element array as a single object. I'm almost sure the RethinkDB query engine is smart enough to make using `nth(0)` much more efficient rather than fetching the whole cursor to an array and taking the latter's first element in your code.